# Unable to use XAML to bind to a property of a class instance when using ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

In my `WPF` project, I'm using [WindowChrome](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome?view=netcore-3.1) to customize my `Mainwindow`. I get the following error when I try to bind a property `LastName` of `Person.xaml.cs` code-behind class of the `Person.Xaml` file shown below:

> > Exception: Cannot find resource named 'prs'. Resource names are case sensitive.

**Remark**

1. The error seems to occur due to the `<local:Person x:Key="prs"/>` reference in the `ResourceDictionary.xaml` file shown below. And the error occurs at line `InitializeComponent();` of the `Persona.xaml.cs` file when 'Person.xaml.cs`class is instantiated in a button click event defined in`ResourceDictionary.xaml.cs` file shown below.
2. The exact same error occurs if I reference `<local:Person x:Key="prs"/>` in the `App.xaml` file instead.
3. HOWEVER, the error does **NOT** occur when I do not use the `ResourceDictionary` to customize the `MainwWindow` and instead reference `<local:Person x:Key="prs"/>` in App.xaml file.

**Question**: What I may be doing wrong, and how can we fix the issue while still using ResourceDictionary to customize the MainWindow?

**Person.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.Commands.Person"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject">

    <Grid>
        <Label>Last Name:</Label>
        <TextBox Name="txtLastName">
            <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="LastName" Source="{StaticResource prs}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                </Binding>
            </TextBox.Text>
        </TextBox>
 </Grid>
</Window
```

**Person.xaml.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Commands
{
  public partial class Person: Window
  {
      public Person()
      {
          InitializeComponent(); //the above ERROR occurs here
      }

      public string LastName
      {
          get { return txtLastName.Text; }
      }
  }
}
```

**ResourceDictionary.xaml**: The Data Source `<local:Person x:Key="pers"/>` is referenced here in first line

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="MyProject.WindowStyle"
                    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Commands">

<local:Person x:Key="pers"/>

    <Style x:Key="CustomWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="30"
                              CornerRadius="4"
                              GlassFrameThickness="0"
                              NonClientFrameEdges="None"
                              ResizeBorderThickness="5"
                              UseAeroCaptionButtons="False" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="5,30,5,5">
                            <AdornerDecorator>
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </AdornerDecorator>
                        </Border>

                        <DockPanel Height="30"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                   LastChildFill="False">

                            <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       Foreground="White"
                                       Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" />

                            <Button x:Name="btnClose"
                                    Width="15"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Click="CloseClick"
                                    Content="X"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />


                            <Button x:Name="btnRestore"
                                    Width="15"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    Click="MaximizeRestoreClick"
                                    Content="#"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />

                            <Button x:Name="btnMinimize"
                                    Width="15"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Click="MinimizeClick"
                                    Content="_"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />

                            <Button x:Name="btnAddPerson"
                                    Width="15"
                                    Margin="5"
                                    VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"
                                    Click="btnAddPerson_Click"
                                    Content="_"
                                    DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                                    WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" />

                        </DockPanel>

                    </Grid>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**ResourceDictionary.xaml.cs**:

```
namespace SciDoxViewer
{
    public partial class WindowStyle : ResourceDictionary
    {
        public WindowStyle()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
     
        //Here: click events for other buttons in above ResourceDictionary.xaml file
        ...............
        ...............
        private void btnAddPerson_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                Person person = new Person(); //This line first takes you to `InitializeComponent();` of the constructor of `Person` class where the above error occurs.

                if (person.ShowDialog() == true)
                {
                    .....
                }
        }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE** [on date: Nov. 05, 2020]

`WindowStyle.xaml` is referenced in `MainWindow` (and NOT in `Person.xaml`) as follows.
**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Style="{StaticResource CustomWindowStyle}">
<Grid>
....
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**App.xaml**:

```
<Application x:Class="MyProject.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SciDoxViewer.Commands"
             xmlns:main="clr-namespace:MyProject"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">

    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyProject;component/WindowStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>       
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you posted that would put the `WindowStyle` resource dictionary into the search path for the `Person` window where you want to reference the resource. What makes you think it should work? Also, please do not elide portions of the code example. If the elided code is not important, don't mention it at all. Provide an actual [mcve] that is self-contained, minimal, and **complete**.

Comment: @PeterDuniho After reading your comments, I have just added the missing parts of the `<Window...>` tag of the `Person.xaml` file.

Comment: This will not work. You can't have a Person class with XAML that contains a Binding which uses an instance of the same class as Source. CustomWindowStyle should be declared in Person.xaml.

Comment: @nam: Where is the `ResourceDictionary` being merged/referenced into the window?

Comment: @mm8 To answer your question, I've added an **UPDATE** section. Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: @nam: Why are you creating a `Person` resource in the resource dictionary and then creating another `Person` window in the click event handler...do you need two instances?

Comment: @mm8 Your question makes me think, I may be doing something wrong here. Person.xaml is just like a custom dialogbox that is opened by the click event `btnAddPerson_Click(...)` in the `WindowStyle.xaml.cs` file. User enters FirstName, LastName etc., click ok. The same click event captures the user inputs and deal with. Maybe, Person resource is not needed in the resource dictionary, correct?

Comment: @nam: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: @mm8 I just tested by removing Person resource in the resource dictionary, and it worked (thank you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `Person` resource from the resource dictionary since you already create another instance of the `Person` window in the click event handler. The resource is not used anyway.